# Diversified product and diversified person

Tags: usage, word-usage

Is it ok to use the word "diversified" for a human the same way we use it for a product? For example is it correct to say "he is a diversified person" or "he is a diversified specialist"? Does it sound natural?

Comment: In American English, "diversified" is used for a "product portfolio", or a company (which makes or distributes a range of products), or a securities fund (which owns a "portfolio of securities"); it is not used for a single product.  This usage of "portfolio" means "a group of things, in a context where the ownership matters".

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**
While "a diversified person" is *grammatically* correct, it is awkward and unclear usage, does not sound natural, and should be avoided.  Figure out what exactly it is that is diverse about the person, and describe that instead.

**Long answer:**
Firstly, "diversified" means "to have made or have become more diverse".  Why use the past participle?  If you want to use an adjective, why not "a diverse person"?

But even "a diverse person" is awkward usage.  "Diverse" means *different from each other; made up of people or things that are different from each other*. (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diverse)  What does "a diverse person" mean?  "A person who is made up of distinct or unlike elements"?  If we want to call attention to the things that are different, it would be better to say exactly what is different.  For example, "a person *of diverse interests*" or "a person *of diverse skills*".

You can see the relative usage of diverse and diversified here:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diverse+person%2Cdiversified+person%2Cdiverse+range%2Cdiversified+range%2Cdiverse+skills%2Cdiversified+skills%2Cdiverse+interests%2Cdiversified+interests&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiverse%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiverse%20range%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiversified%20range%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiverse%20skills%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiversified%20skills%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiverse%20interests%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiversified%20interests%3B%2Cc0
You will see that "diverse" is much more common than "diversified", and that both terms are much more commonly applied to a range or collection of things than to a person, and "diversified person" doesn't even appear!

Answer (score -2):

*Someone is a diversified person* -is ***absolutely fine.***

Because, there, you use *diversified* as an adjective.

One of the results from Google Books:

> What of Leonardo da Vinci, a brilliant Renaissance man, and perhaps the most creatively ***diversified person*** to ever have lived? - *Take the Leap*

Another examples from Google Book results are [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=RT5EyY1V3DEC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=%22a%20diversified%20person%22&source=bl&ots=hiU4Oyc1I7&sig=o_buuF0e8OFcYAipzhgU4b2AKeE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vUzQVIzsKpe58gW3xIKACg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22a%20diversified%20person%22&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=DBAtlw90wN8C&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=%22a%20diversified%20person%22&source=bl&ots=JheeMuca48&sig=6Uis7kyZXB_P70ZvzKOQOCQIQOs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vUzQVIzsKpe58gW3xIKACg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22a%20diversified%20person%22&f=false).

A statement as written in [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/zackomalleygreenburg/2012/09/05/ludacris-dreams-a-rap-mogul-diversifies-his-empire/):

> Because to be diversified in business, you have to be ***a diversified person***

Comment: That result has the wrong words bolded. He's not a diversified person, he's a *creatively diversified* person -- his creativity has many diverse manifestations. So no, "a diversified person" is **not** fine, because, as strangdon says, the very definition of "diversified"/"diverse" is rather plural and works badly when applied to a singular person.

Comment: @A.Beth I'll still stand by my words! :) However, adding more examples for your concern